# using Cyrillic characters in URL get request

Tags: ios, swift, url

I need to create GET request like this:

[https://public-api.nazk.gov.ua/v1/declaration/?q=Чер](https://public-api.nazk.gov.ua/v1/declaration/?q=%D0%A7%D0%B5%D1%80)

[https://public-api.nazk.gov.ua/v1/declaration/?q=Володимирович](https://public-api.nazk.gov.ua/v1/declaration/?q=%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87)

Last characters after = are Cyrillic symbols

```
    let hostURL = "https://public-api.nazk.gov.ua/v1/declaration/?q="
    let url = URL(string: (hostURL + searchBar.text!))!
```

I have a run time error because it is impossible to force unwrap Cyrillic symbols. How can I avoid this issue?

Comment: Instead of completely changing your question, please post a new question specific to your new issue about decoding the obtained data.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this.

```
let hostURL = "https://public-api.nazk.gov.ua/v1/declaration/?q="
hostURL = hostURL + searchBar.text!

let encodedUrl = hostURL.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)

let url = URL(string:encodedUrl)
```

Comment: Just encode the `searchBar.text`, not the whole URL.

Comment: @maddy,, Yes, that is another possible solution.

Comment: I got "Use of unresolved identifier 'URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet'"

Comment: @loann Will, i have updated my answer. Can you please check now?

Comment: still get in console:"https://public-api.nazk.gov.ua/v1/declaration/?q=%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD
Trying to decode data...
Either no data was returned, or data was not properly decoded." it works fine with integers in search condition but not with Cyrillic text(